# In Android how to concatenate base64 encoded strings?

Tags: android

Please help me to solve this:

**I have two strings for email-id and password like**

```
String name = "xyz@gmail.com";
String pass = "abc";
```

**I encode these two into Base64 string like**

```
String encoded_name = new String(Base64.encode(name.getBytes(), 0));
String encoded_pass = new String(Base64.encode(pass.getBytes(), 0));
```

**and I need to concatenate these two encoded strings with space like**

```
String merge = encoded_name + " " + encoded_pass;
```

**I checked this string in console by**

```
System.out.print("Concatenate string= " + merge);
```

but in console I am getting result in two lines like this

```
11-18 00:25:29.898: INFO/System.out(1244): Merge= eHl6QGdtYWlsLmNvbQ==
11-18 00:25:29.908: INFO/System.out(1244):  YWJj
```

Why is this happing the result is unexpected for me why it is not printing in a single line. please help me to solve this.

Thanks

Comment: I have never used System.out to show information in android, can you try with the Log class? Log.e("BASE64", merge);

Comment: Check if your Base64 string ends with a "newline", or remove it with *String.trim()*.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You should use the NO_WRAP flag as described in the [Docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/Base64.html#NO_WRAP), the Base64 class will not add additional newlines.

> **NO_WRAP:** Encoder flag bit to omit all line terminators (i.e., the output will be on one long line).

So change your lines to the following:

```
String encoded_name = new String(Base64.encode(name.getBytes(), Base64.NO_WRAP));
String encoded_pass = new String(Base64.encode(pass.getBytes(), Base64.NO_WRAP));
```

This will output the following:

```
11-17 19:16:51.283: INFO/System.out(354): Concatenate string= eHl6QGdtYWlsLmNvbQ== YWJj
```

Answer (score 1):

Please have a look on [Android Api reference Document](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/Base64.html). It will solve all other queries regarding Base64 encoding/decoding in android.

one more efficient way to solve your problem:

```
String encoded_name = Base64.encodeToString(name.getBytes("utf-8"), Base64.NO_WRAP);
String encoded_pass = Base64.encodeToString(pass.getBytes("utf-8"), Base64.NO_WRAP);
```

out put:-

```
11-17 10:55:27.492: V/BASE-64-.encodeToString(525): eHl6QGdtYWlsLmNvbQ== YWJj
```

Answer (score 0):

Look at [this doc](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64), the mime section states that

MIME does not specify a fixed length for Base64-encoded lines, but it does specify a maximum  line length of 76 characters. Additionally it specifies that any extra-alphabetic characters must be ignored by a compliant decoder, although most implementations use a CR/LF newline pair to delimit encoded lines.

You should only consider removing  the last char of your first base 64 string, it seems to be a \n (a more generic method would be to test wether it is or not.)

Regards,
 Stéphane