# Android WebChromeClient integration with javaScript gives Unexpected Illegal token

Tags: javascript, android, webview, webchromeclient

Home.java

```
public void updatePhoto(Bitmap bitmap) {
   String bitmapStr = BitMapToString(bitmap);
   Home.currentBmp = bitmap;

   String parameter = "data:image/jpeg;base64," + bitmapStr;

   webView1.loadUrl("javascript:var script = document.createElement('script');" + 
      "script.type='text/javascript';script.src='form.js';" + 
      "script.onload=" + "processImage('" + parameter + "');" +
      //"script.onload=" + "processImage(':/;//');" +
      "document.getElementsByTagName('head').item(0).appendChild(script);");
   Log.v(parameter, "QWERTY");
   Log.v("QWERTY", parameter);
}
```

form.js

```
function processImage(img) {
   alert('process image end');
}
```

this function converts the Bitmap object into a base64 String, then executes an external javascript `function (form.js -> processImage(var))`. However it doesn't execute processImage and gives an Uncaught `SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL`. However when i uncomment the

```
//"script.onload=" + "processImage(':/;//');" +
```

line and comment in

```
"script.onload=" + "processImage('" + parameter + "');" +
```

it seems that the function is working well. The possible value for parameter variable would be

```
data:image/jpeg;base64,iVBORw0KgoAAAANSHUEgAAA......
```

What I am asking is how am I gonna make the javaScript function work with the parameter? Thanks!

Comment: I don't think your `BitMapToString` is working correctly, also you'll have to wrap `processImage` in a function to pass it to `script.onload`.

Comment: Thanks I actually forgot to encrypt the string. I followed steps [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8172730/in-android-how-to-concatenate-base64-encoded-strings) to encrypt the string with no wraps .. Thanks @Musa  !!

Comment: @RjMatt hi, I am looking extatly for your solution, have you find out best  BitMapToString function ?